# Convert UTC time in brazil time using noda time in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nodatime

I am working in MVC4 project .In this project i need to convert UTC time ,which i am getting from server to brazil time zone.

How can i convert UTC time to brazil time in noda time library.

Comment: How are you receiving the UTC time? What do you then want to do with the value in the Brazilian time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, if you can get the value as an `Instant` to start with, it's as simple as:

```
var instant = ...; // However you're receiving that
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Sao_Paulo"];
var inBrazil = instant.InZone(zone);
```